# Remove nearby dots and single dots in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-re

how can i change consistent dots(more than 2) to one single dot, and where now one single dot replace it to space. [image]

Comment: use `str.replace(old, new[, count])` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace => "." to " ", then " . . . " to " . "

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question by pasting the input text into the question not as an image. Do you mean `.задачи...концептуальной.модели.предметной.области...концептуальных` etc, or are there additional spaces `. задачи . . . концептуальной . модели` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `s` is a string of your data, you can use `s.replace('.', ' ')` to replace all dots with spaces. Note that this would also replace consecutive dots to spaces.

To solve this, use a while loop to first replace all consecutive dots to 2 dots, then replace all 2 dots to a temporary string, replace single dots with spaces and then the temporary string to one dot.

A script to do that could look like this:

```
# s is your datastring

while '...' in s:
    s = s.replace('...', '..')
s = s.replace('..', '<temp>')
s = s.replace('.', ' ')
s = s.replace('<temp>', '.')
```

That's a lot of replaces, but it should deal with any amount of consecutive dots and other edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, with the **sub()** method.

```
# String
s = 'задачи...концептуальной.модели.предметной.области...концептуальных'

# Pattern to match from one or more dots 
dot_pattern = re.compile(r'\.{1,}')

# call the sub method
single_dot = dot_pattern.sub(' ', s) 

# ...
print(single_dot) 

# output:
'задачи концептуальной модели предметной области концептуальных'
```

Comment: I don't think the question can be meaningfully answered until the OP has clarified what the input string consists of. The image suggests that it may contain additional spaces.

Comment: Currently the program changes the dots ('...', '..', '.') by the space character.